# Why is the navbar in Bootstrap 5 not responsive?

Tags: html, navbar

I'm a newbie.

Below is the navbar code from Bootstrap 5.3 but the text is not responsive.  What do I need to add?

`


THIS IS THE LOGO

`

I tried to put  "navbar-expand-lg" in the nav class but that didn't work.

Comment: You forgot to add code

Comment: Can you please add some code so then we can understand you problem a bit easier